# Adding NSDictionary key into one table view and values corresponding to the key in another table view swift 4

Tags: uitableview, swift4, nsdictionary

Create a `NSDictionary` having country names as `keys` and the state of country as `values` and I want to display state corresponding to a country into another tableView

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not a good idea to use `NSDictionary` in swift, you can use `Dictionary`, in your case it can be `[String: [String]]`.

You can create a `Dictionary` in swift like this:

```
    var countries = [
        "country 1": "state one",
        "country 2": "state 2"
    ]
```

To access the `value`  just do like this:  `let state = countries["country 1"]`

---

**UPDATE**

to make it with an array of states it is the same.

```
    var countries = [
        "country 1": [
            "state 1",
            "state2","state3",
            "state4"
        ],
        "country 2": [
            "otherstate 1",
            "otherstate",
            "otherstate",
            "otherstate"
        ]
    ]
```

access array of values:

```
let states = countries["country 1"] as! [String]

    for state in states {
        print(state)
    }
```

Comment: I want array of states as values in NSdictionary

Comment: how can i access the array elements inside this NSDictionary values?

Comment: how can I print that array of states in table view

Comment: you have the array of states now. it is very easy, we are not here to learn you how to code in swift.